# Pass Argument in Command line and get full path

Tags: c#, filepath

I have two Directory in D drive my PC

```
D:\My First Directory 
D:\My Second Directory
```

when I am pass this two argument in console program in C#

like this :

```
Program.exe D:\My First Directory D:\My Second Directory
```

I access this this of output.

```
args[0] : D:\My
args[1] : First 
args[2] : Directory 
args[3] : D:\My 
args[4] : Second 
args[5] : Directory
```

I want to this type of output :

```
args[0] : D:\My First Directory 
args[1] : D:\My Second Directory
```

Comment: Put each path in quotes.

Comment: this is  easy way to access I want to without quotes

Comment: So,you want something that goes against how the OS works?

Comment: This is how every application that takes command-line args works.  Every single one.  So why do you want yours to work differently?  How do you know what is part of dir 1 and part of dir 2.  I know...when the drive letter starts.  So why don't you do string manip yourself and just find the drive letters to delimit your paths?

Comment: Not all paths must begin with the drive letter @rory.ap :)

Comment: suppose any user pass argument without quotes and path is correct so??? what to do?

Comment: @Pikoh -- they all begin with a finite set of things that can be used to split, none of which can show up elsewhere twice in a single path.

Comment: _"suppose any user pass argument without quotes and path is correct so??? what to do? "_  You put up a message that says `Path not found. Please use quotes around the path`.   That or `Please do not press that button again`

Comment: Just try to remove any quotes (that they may or may not have put in), then quote it yourself

Comment: Bottom line: the principle of least astonishment is at play here (look it up).  Users *expect* that an application will want quotes around individual args that have spaces.  If your app doesn't do that, then they'll be "astonished"..or more likely, annoyed.

Comment: A directory name may have two consecutive spaces.  So, in the general case, any attempt to reconstitute the paths from a command line that doesn't quote them is doomed to failure.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do it is to pass the arguments inside double quotes, like this:

```
Program.exe "D:\My First Directory" "D:\My Second Directory"
```

There is no other simple way.
Operating system just works like that. One string is one argument.

You could do some wise mechanism though. 
I wouldn't do it, I would just put those directories in double quotes.

But if I for some reason REALLY, REALLY had to do it, I'd do it like that:

- get all the arguments into one string
- magically split this string into list (array) of strings, using regular expressions (looking for string like: "D:\", of course as a regular expression).

But it could only work if you can only have directories in arguments and nothing else.

Comment: There are some interesting security issues with not using quotes too.  Probably not as likely with your own code... but using unquoted paths as the parameter for a application shortcut has some interesting results.